# trac "OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database" problem with visualsvn

Tags: database, svn, trac

I have installed the latest VisualSVN (2.0.5) and its trac-package on WindowsXP, but ran into a problem. The trac system works, except the "Timeline" tab. When I clicked on it, I saw

```
Oops…
Trac detected an internal error:
OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database
```

Does anybody have any idea, why it does not works? Everything was installed and configured using its manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the owner of the folder where the TRAC enviroment lives

this is check the user that runs the VisualSVN service and give access to this user to the folder where trac runs

this fix me issue

Answer (score 0):

As user163175 said you have to change the owner (or give permission to the web server user).

To do this on Windows (Server Standard) you need to:

- Go to your trac directory (where all the your trac projects live, the one you set as `PythonOption TracEnvParentDir`) in explorer
- Right click and select Properties
- Click on the `Edit...` button
- Click `Add...` button
- Type "NETWORK SERVICE" in to the `Enter the object names to select` input
- Click the `Check Names` button.
- Click on `OK`
- Click on the new NETWORK SERVICE user/group
- Check off "Full Control"
- Click `Apply`

That should do it (at least that worked for me).